# How to fix these few errors in .htaccess: 302 (tempoary) and HTTP/1.1 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So basically, I am checking my page with this site: http://www.ragepank.com/redirect-check/

My domain is http://www.candoboatloans.com.au

I am attempting to remove all errors that RagePank displays.

I managed to fix a few, but there are still a few small problems.

Here are the three small errors:

```
http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/index.htm returns a HTTP/1.1 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: article, htm, contentView response
http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/index.html returns a 302 (temporary) redirect
http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/default.htm returns a HTTP/1.1 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: article, htm, contentView response
```

I added the following to my `.htaccess` file, and it eliminated atleast 10 errors that were going wrong. The code was given to me by RagePank:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.candoboatloans\.com\.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, the code now redirects my mobile site (subdomain), `m.candoboatloans.com.au` to its folder, which is `http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/m`.

Is there any way to only redirect my main domain, and not the subdomain?

How can I remove these other three errors that are occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^candoboatloans\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.candoboatloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That should keep any redirecting happening with your mobile site.

The other three things you listed, 2 of them looks like a problem with your CMS and the other looks like you've set it up so that `index.html` gets redirected to 404.html instead of returning a proper 404 response?

Can probably just fix all three of them by adding this somewhere appropriate:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.html?|default.html?)$ / [L,R=301]
```